# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'editing') for open MathType in Online Builder with React

Tags: ckeditor5, mathtype, ckeditor5-react

### Provide detailed reproduction steps (if any)

1- create a custom build with online builder
2- download and add to root project and install npm with command npm i file:./plugins/ckeditor5
3- npm i ckeditor5/react
4- my codes in a component:

```
import {CKEditor} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor"

<CKEditor
                            editor={Editor}
                            config={editorConfig}
                            onChange={questionHandler}
                            onReady={questionEditorClass}
                        />
```

### Other details

- Browser: chrome and firefox
- OS: MacOs
- First affected CKEditor version: ckeditor5/react 6.1.0
- Installed CKEditor plugins: MathType

---

If you'd like to see this fixed sooner, add a  reaction to this post.

when open MathType or ChemType without problem but open for first time have error in chrome:
[image]

when open MathType or ChemType without problem but open for first time have error in firefox:
[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.